# Remove NETBEANS-ExecEvent lines from maven output in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 maven output in Netbeans shows many annoying lines starting with:

```
[INFO] NETBEANS-ExecEvent: ...
```

Do you know a way to remove these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by adding the following line to the simplelogger.properties file of my maven installation:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.netbeans.modules.maven.event=off
```

It seems that [NbEventSpy](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/master/java/maven/mavensrc/org/netbeans/modules/maven/event/NbEventSpy.java) adds those lines, so the idea is to turn off logging from `org.netbeans.modules.maven.event`

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug. these lines should be hidden but they do happen to me sometimes. In my case the reason is that the line is too long, gets cut off and is eventually not recognize

Comment: In my case there are more than twenty of these lines in a simple build. They appear to be debug infos and there should be a way to disable them. What is strange is that they popped up after a distro upgrade, but Netbeas was installed manually and didn't change during the upgrade. Another strange thing is that now the output is colorized.